# Setting up SSL on AWS EC2

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ssl

I'm trying to set up SSL on my wordpress site.

I've an EC2 instance running wordpress on nginx and ubuntu. Database running on RDS.

I've launched an application load balancer with listeners on ports 80 and 443 and attached the SSL certificate which I got via ACM. I've set my targets to point to the EC2 instance I am using.

At this point the how-to guides and information stops. Apparently that's all there is to it and it should now all be working. However it's not. I'm getting connection refused errors when I add the https to my site's URL.

When I put my URL into https://www.sslchecker.com/sslchecker I'm told that no certificates are found.

So clearly I need to something more to get this working - can anyone point me to the next step?

Comment: Did you actually point your domain to the load balancer? It sounds like it may be pointing directly to the EC2 server.

Comment: I didn't make any changes to the DNS - none of the tutorials mentioned that and I'm not entirely sure how to do that

Comment: If your DNS isn't pointing to the load balancer then you aren't using the load balancer.

Answer (score -1):

Using the ELB and ACB is the way to go here.  It sounds like you might be using the wrong type of ELB though.  You mentioned application load balancer, you should use a classic load balancer.  Also make sure your security groups are setup correctly to allow your ELB to talk to the EC2 instance.

You didn't mention Route53 but I assume you have the DNS entry setup to point at the ELB as well.

Share more and I will help more. Good luck.

Comment: Why would the classic ELB be prefered over an ALB at this point?

Comment: Mark, I think pricing would be the main reason. But that could really vary depending on usage patterns I suppose.  But I think more to your point.. his issue isn't really the ALB but probably a security group.

Comment: ALB is usually cheaper than ELB, and it supports newer features like HTTP/2 and web sockets. I really wouldn't recommend anyone keep using the classic ELB at this point.

Comment: Interesting... I am using about 19 ELBs in a production ENV. I'll switch some over and monitor the cost.  Thanks for sharing @MarkB.